# Automatically create Object from layout in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-layout, android-studio

I was wondering if there is a way to automatically extract all the views from a layout and to generate the java code.

For example you have a layout : foo.xml

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@id/menu_profile_image"
  android:layout_centerVertical="true"
  android:padding="20dp"
    >
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
  />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_info"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TODO Quel info ?"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

and it will generate :

```
TextView username = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.username);
TextView userInfo= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user_info);
```

Comment: Butter Knife will at least make it less cumbersome: http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Comment: It looks quite nice thak you!

Comment: https://github.com/Kotlin/anko

Answer (score 1):

In android studios you can try [Android Studio Prettify](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7405) plugin

It have following features:

- Generator for inflater and activity setContentView view variables
- "Extract String resource" shortcut in context menu
- LineMarker for view types
- View cast checking annotator
- Field and method variable generator for views
- Related layout files for nested classes
- Symbol search for layout id in xml files